# Android Navigation drawer after 2 activities

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, dashboard

i am developing an app in which there is a first **login** and **sign up** activity and after successful login there is dashboard... i want to have dashboard activity with navigation drawer and first two activities (login and sign up ) without navigation drawer how can i do that... i have searched this on this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: You can make first activity to show user log in and register button and after you can show dashboard of navigation drawer.

Comment: yes.. but how to do this ,, can u explain me.. ?

Comment: show login activity in starting of Application and once it is logged in send user to dashboard.

Comment: in the link i provided here... i only came to know about navigation drawer but dont know about how to relate with other activities.. should i use intent ??

Comment: yes, Use intent for changing Activity.

Comment: i tried it but not working... can u provide me any good example of my requirement any link ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Intent` to go to another activity from one activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your Case:

when user press login button check that `username` and `password` is right. if it is right put this code or say execute it.

Comment: I tried and get it.. the mistake i was doing is that i was not changing the launch up or the default activity to the LOGIN activity in manifest..

Answer (score 0):

I done this today only....Done Registration and verification Activity then all required login process then had this tutorial for navigation drawer [Navigation drawer example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

in this example there is Mainactivity.java. I renamed it to start_screen.java and my logic necessary. then just simple

```
Intent i = new Intent(Login_screen.this,Start_Screen.class);
```

From login_screen.java.

navigation drawer will pop up like

[image]